# Running single test in IntelliJ Idea 2021.2.3 (Ultimate edition) sometimes not offered

Tags: intellij-idea, spock

I have the Java project (Maven/Spring/Spock). It appears that I couldn't run single test in test suite (class) randomly.
In some test classes it possible, in some other its not - entire test suite is the only available choice.
This is annoying while debuging single test.

[image: Cannot run single test - offers running entire suite]

[image: Can run single test]

Is there any setting/choice how to avoid this disbalance? Thanks

Comment: Try [EAP version of IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/). Should have been fixed in the scope of https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-233864

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov if you post it as answer, then OP can accept it and others can see that this question has been resolved..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [EAP version of IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/). Should have been fixed in the scope of [youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-233864](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-233864)